# Why my navbar-toggler show the navbar-item on default

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I wonder why the nav-items keeps showing every time I refresh the page in mobile view. I checked the aria-expanded: false but still it does not work.

This is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light">
        <div class="container-fluid justify-content-between mx-5 px-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HELLO</a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler collapse collapsed"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">

            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <li class="navbar-item">
                <a class="nav-link active " aria-current="page" href="#">ABOUT</a>
              </li>
              <li class="navbar-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page"href="#">PROJECT</a>
              </li class="navbar-item">
              <li class="navbar-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">RESUME</a>
              </li>
              <li class="navbar-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">CONTACT</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </nav>
      <!-- <img class="img-fluid" src="img\heading-image.jpg" alt=""> -->
    </header>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please note: I'm still a beginner in bootstrap, html and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the class `collapse collapsed`  from button and add `collapse`to a menu  div

here is the full code

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
     
     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light"
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HELLO</a>
         
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler "
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse"
            aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">

            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse " id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <li class="navbar-item">
                <a class="nav-link active " aria-current="page" href="#">ABOUT</a>
              </li>
              <li class="navbar-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page"href="#">PROJECT</a>
              <li class="navbar-item">
              <li class="navbar-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">RESUME</a>
              </li>
              <li class="navbar-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">CONTACT</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

      </nav>
      <!-- <img class="img-fluid" src="img\heading-image.jpg" alt=""> -->
    </header>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It runs well on the snippet but when I copy to my file, the same result happened. I'm running the file through chrome.

Comment: try  with adding bootstrap script file in header instead of adding in bottom of body

Comment: Thank you! But somehow I fix it through my javascript. I misplaced the code on showing the items through javascript. It solved the problem when I delete the code from javascript